# Sequence spaces - every sequence converges to a number. Does this make the sequence space compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X\subsetneq c$ be a sequence space such that every sequence of numbers converges to a number over which the sequences in $X$ range.  Is this enough to make the sequence space compact?

I'm aware of the issue here.  Convergent sequences of numbers are not themselves convergent sequences of sequences in $X$.  But it seems plausible that if the sequences themselves all converge to elements of some sequence, then it could imply cauchy sequences of sequences converge to sequences.

Comment: Every element of $c_0$ is a sequence that converges to $0$ by definition, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @s.harp sorry, careless. I've changed to $c$.

Comment: @s.harp p.s. with respect to *what am I asking*, it works in $X\subsetneq c_0$.  Suppose a subset $X$ of $c_0$ contained no sequence containing the number $0$.  Then it would not satsfy the criteria I give in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the 2-dimensional vector space with basis the sequences $u_n = 1/n^2$ (for even terms, 0 otherwise) and $v_n=1/n$ (still for even $n$). This vector space is obviously homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it's not compact. Maybe you're thinking about completeness.

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is my somewhat naive understanding of the nuances of these topological properties.  Nevertheless this is a helpful counterexample and (i think) an illustration of unboundedness.